# Oracle sql query that returns customers who are coming for the first time in property

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables: **customer**, **property** and **stays**. Table customer contains all the data about customers (`customer_id, name, surname, email...`). Table property contains the list of all the properties (`property_id, property_name...`) and table stays contains all the earlier stays of customers (`customer_id, property_id, stay_id, arrival_date, departure_date...`).

Some customers stayed multiple times in more than one properties and some customers are coming for the first time. 
Can someone please explain oracle sql query which returns only the customers who are stying in any of the properties for the first time.

Sorry guys for answering late..
This is what I got so far.

Tables:
Customer             $A$

Stays                $B$

Property             $C$

Customer_Fragments   $D$

```
SELECT a.RIID_, 
  sub.CUSTOMER_ID_, 
  sub.PROPERTY_ID, 
  b.ARRIVAL_DATE, 
  c.PROPERTY_SEGMENT, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY sub.CUSTOMER_ID_, 
    sub.PROPERTY_ID 
    ORDER BY 
      sub.CUSTOMER_ID_ asc
  ) RN 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      b.CUSTOMER_ID_, 
      b.PROPERTY_ID 
    FROM 
      $B$ b 
    GROUP BY 
      b.CUSTOMER_ID_, 
      b.PROPERTY_ID 
    HAVING 
      COUNT(*)= 1
  ) sub 
  INNER JOIN $A$ a ON sub.CUSTOMER_ID_ = a.CUSTOMER_ID_ 
  INNER JOIN $B$ b ON sub.CUSTOMER_ID_ = b.CUSTOMER_ID_ 
  INNER JOIN $C$ c ON sub.PROPERTY_ID = c.PROPERTY_ID 
  LEFT JOIN $D$ d ON a.RIID_ = d.RIID_ 
WHERE 
  b.ARRIVAL_DATE = TRUNC(SYSDATE + 7) 
  AND c.PROPERTY_DESTINATION = 'Destination1' 
  AND lower(c.NAME_) NOT LIKE ('unknown%') 
  AND a.NWL_PERMISSION_STATUS = 'I'  
  AND a.EMAIL_DOMAIN_ NOT IN ('abuse.com', 'guest.booking.com')
  AND (d.BLACKLISTED != 'Y' 
    or d.BLACKLISTED is null
  )
```

I want to select all customers who will come to Destination1, 7days from today to inform them about some activities. Customers can book several
properties in Destination1 and have the same arrival date (example: I can book a room in property1 for me and my wife and also book a room in property2 for my friends.. and we all come to destination1 on the same arrival date).
When this is the case I want to send just one info email to a customer and not two emails. The above SQL query returns two rows when this is the case and I want it to return just one row (one row = one email).

Comment: Please read https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/ for an introduction on how to ask a good question regarding SQL. Then **[EDIT]** your question and add the missing information as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), do **NOT** post code in comments.

Comment: There are some ways to word this and some related approaches in SQL: 1) set of people in now **minus** set of people in before. 2) people in now where **not exists** a previous stay. 3) persons where we **count** only one stay. *(SQL keywords are bold.)*

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH first_stays (customer_id, property_id, first_time_arrival_date, stay_no) AS
(
    SELECT s.customer_id
         , s.property_id
         , s.arrival_date AS first_time_arrival_date
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.customer_id, s.property_id ORDER BY s.arrival_date) stay_no
      FROM stays s
)
SELECT c.surname AS customer_surname
     , c.name AS customer_name
     , p.property_name
     , s.first_time_arrival_date
  FROM customer c
 INNER
  JOIN first_stays s
    ON s.customer_id = c.customer_id
   AND s.stay_no = 1
 INNER
  JOIN property p
    ON p.property_id = s.property_id
```

The first part `WITH first_stays` is a CTE (Common Table Expression, called [subquery factoring](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF30048) in Oracle) that will number the stays for each pair `(customer_id, property_id)` ordered by the arrival date using a window function [ROW_NUMBER()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm). Then just join those values to the customer and property tables to get their names or whatever, and apply `stay_no = 1` (first stay) condition.

Comment: Thank you very much MarcinJ..When I start the query I'm getting the missing right parenthesis error and don't know what is causing it..it seems to be all good with the statement..

Comment: @val505 Sorry, there was a typo in the `ORDER BY` clause of `ROW_NUMBER`, I've fixed it now and it should work fine. If it does work for you and produces the right results, please consider accepting the answer so that it helps to know other users it's the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

It is always required to post a code you have already tried to write so that we can than help you with eventual mistakes.

After that being said, I'll try to help you nevertheless, writing the full code.
Try this:

```
select cus.*
  from customers cus
  join stays st
    on st.customer_id = cus.customer_id
 where st.arrival_date >= YOUR_DATE --for example SYSDATE or TRUNC(SYSDATE)
   and 1 = (select count(*)
              from stays st2
             where st2.customer_id = cus.customer_id)
```

You haven't specified it, but I GUESS that you are interested in getting the first-time-customers whose arrival date will be at or after some specified date. I've written that into my code in `WHERE clause`, where you should input such a date.

If you remove that part of the `WHERE clause`, you'll get all the customers that stayed just once (even if that one and only stay was 10 years ago, for example). What's more, if you remove that part of the code, you can than also remove the `join on stays st` table from the query too, as the only reason for that join was the need to have access to arrival date.

If you need explanations for some other parts of the code too, ask in the comments for this answer.

I hope I helped!

Comment: Thank you very much Goran for nice explanation..I'm having problems executing the query because the database is big and i'm getting the timeout error..

Comment: @val505 do you have indexes on column `customer_id` in `customers` table and on columns `customer_id` and `arrival_date` in `stays` table? If not, creation of those indexes would greatly improve the performance of any query on those tables that is using those columns in comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, this is not a complicated query:

```
select c.*
from c join
     (select s.customer_id
      from stays s
      group by s.customer_id
      having count(*) = 1
     ) s
     on s.customer_id = c.customer_id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the query.